# Force system to use NTP time

Tags: ntpd

Usually `ntpd` will refuse to change (or slew) system time if difference is too large.

Is there some way (possibly via `ntpq`) to tell `ntpd`: "jump to whatever time you think is right"?

Specifically it should be a "jump if synchronized" action.

I would like to avoid, if possible `killall -HUP ntpd && ntpd -g` or equivalent commands

Comment: Have a look at `ntpdate`.

Comment: You also might want to have a look at the `iburst` and `burst` otpions for `ntpd`.

Comment: @JRFerguson: AFAIK `ntpdate` is currently deprecated; anyways it will not work with a running `ntpd`, so calling it would involve stopping `ntpd` anyways.

Comment: @Thomas: Thanks Tomas, but I already have `iburst` in my config... and it would mean restarting `ntpd`. I am starting to suspect restarting the daemon is the only solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using sntp:

```
sudo sntp -s time.nist.gov
```

For a full list of the NIST time-server IP addresses, see https://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-g` flag on startup of the daemon.

From the man page for `ntpd`,

> `-g` Normally, `ntpd` exits if the offset exceeds the sanity limit, which is 1000s by default. [...] This option overrides the limit and allows the time to be set to any value without restriction; however, this can happen only once. After that, `ntpd` will exit if the limit is exceeded.